# Compilation Error while writing Hopping Window in Kafka Streams(Confluent 4.0.0)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I am trying to write aggregation operation on time-windows in Confluent open source 4.0.0 version as below.

```java
KTable<Windowed<String>, aggrTest> testWinAlerts =
    testRecords.groupByKey()
               .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(120))
                                      .advanceBy(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)))
               .aggregate(
                   new aggrTestInitilizer(), 
                   new minMaxCalculator(),
                   Materialized.<String, aggrTest, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                       as("queryable-store-name")
                           .withValueSerde(aggrMessageSerde)
                           .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()));
```

But above code gives error while compilation as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method aggregate(Initializer<VR>, Aggregator<? super String,? super TestFields,VR>, Materialized<String,VR,WindowStore<Bytes,byte[]>>) in the type TimeWindowedKStream<String,TestFields> is not applicable for the arguments (aggrTestInitilizer, minMaxCalculator, Materialized<String,aggrTest,WindowStore<Bytes,byte[]>>)
```

Same code when I write in 3.3.1 version as below, it does not give any error

```java
KTable<Windowed<String>, aggrTest> testWinAlerts =
    testRecords.groupByKey()
               .aggregate(
                   new aggrTestInitilizer(),
                   new minMaxCalculator(),
                   TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(120))
                              .advanceBy(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)),
                   aggrMessageSerde,
                   "aggr-test");
```

What might be issue? Also `aggrTestInitilizer, minMaxCalculator, aggrMessageSerde` used in all cases are same.

Comment: I had the same proble, it is the Ktable, iirespective u use kafka or the confluent where K-Table uses rocks db, which is supported in limited windows architecture... Moved to Linux which works flawless

Comment: @NirajSanghani it is compilation problem, besides I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: Ahhhh! then i think Windowed key value pair issue

Comment: Can't spot the error atm. What happens when you remove the Materialized parameter? Btw: it seems you don't care about the state store parameter: for this case, you can also omit it, and use `Materialized.with(...)` -- also, if the key-serde is set in `StreamsConfig` you can also pass in `null`

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I have replaced `Materialized.as` with `Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), aggrMessageSerde)`. Its working now, thanks. Also by any way, can we disable this Materialized store in version 4.0.0, as it slows down my process?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax what is difference between `Materialized.as` and `Materialized.with` ?

Comment: Both allow you to specify optional parameters. So it's more or less the same. We use different names for different options to make it sound more like natural language.